# Half-programming, half-law question

Tags: discussion

I am running a simple **file-sharing website** (http://gget.it for instance), and have a half-law / half-programming question.
Is it suited for SO, meta.SO, or for another SE site ? *(I know this question will be "closed, deleted, marked as duplicate, as off-topic, as too-broad, as opinion-based" at the same time, but where is the right place to post it? If possible, can you move it to the right place?)*

---

> **What can I do, in order to protect myself in the case people upload
>   forbidden content on the file-sharing website ?** (ex: terrorism, forbidden porn, piracy, etc.)

**What can be done in order to prevent me from being brought to trial / justice for content some users may host on this website?**

- Are they some technical / programming solutions : algorithms that filter the content and analyze if it is forbidden?
- Are there some legal solutions: legal mentions that would protect me, and say I don't have legal responsability for hosted content?

*PS: once again, I know this question doesn't fullfill the SO question standards, how could I modify it / post it in the right place so that it meets these requirements?*

Comment: Legal questions are off topic for any site on the network. There are surely not going to be any automated filters that can detect "forbidden" content.

Comment: That's not a programming question, as there's _very_ little you can do to analyze the type of content users upload (Doing that is another legal issue, actually).

Comment: This is a full-law question. Always assume that all filters that can be implemented are imperfect. Thus the remaining question is, how do you protect yourself legally once someone manages to get an illegal file past your filters.

Comment: @Basj Without answering your question, I would note that reasonable laws and regulations often produce at least the appearance of compliance in industry ... and so studying other ISPs and websites policies on these issues, like copyright, DMCA takedown, terms of service, cooperation with law enforcement, etc., may take you a long way without ever asking anyone on Stack Exchange.  Asking would mostly bring you opinions whereas the facts of actual policies are all around you.

Comment: You'd not only better consult a lawyer, you'd better find a good one in case something bad happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a programming question, as there's very little you can do to analyze the type of content users upload (Doing that is another legal issue, actually).

Since this is a "law / legal" question, and there are no SE sites on that subject, the question appears to be off-topic for SE.

[There has been a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3527/software-law) for a software law stack exchange site, but it's been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cerbrus. Do you have an idea where I could find relevant answers on this law/legal question? Up to now, Google didn't give me very relevant answers (maybe my research was not well done).

Comment: @Basj a lawyer.

Comment: Before hiring a lawyer, I can imagine that many people (who host user-ploaded-content), probably millions of people should have had the same question already (everyone who has a phpBB forum that hosts attachment!). There might be some sort of "obvious" answer, don't you think so @Joe ?

Comment: @Basj the "obvious" answer is _never take legal advice from random strangers on the internet_ because in court, "somebody on SO / a forum / reddit said so" is not a valid defense. Also, the laws probably differ depending on thousands of factors, from location to law form of the company/person owning the site - a private phpBB that is spammed with warez will probably be handled differently from a commercial file hosting service. That said, there are probably many law forums out there where you can get some sort of advice which may or may not be correct.

Comment: Thanks @l4mpi for your comment, you're right. Do you know one of them (a good one?) about law forums? So sad The proposals of law site on SE have been deleted...

Comment: Of course.  They have been deleted for legal reasons.